# Infrastructure network without router

Tags: networking, router, desktop

Is there any way to create an infrastructure network without a router? In other words, is there some way to make a PC behave as a router? Other PCs should be able to see this network as an access point network, not as an Ad-hoc one.

Comment: Wouldn't be Server Fault a bit better place to ask this?

Comment: On Windows use ICS, `ncpa.cpl -> right click NIC -> Advanced -> Allow other users to connect...`.  On Linux, set up NAT (iptables?) can't remember how.

Comment: It makes no sense - look at Mikrotik hardware, does all you need for a price FAR lower than the PC you are wasting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use [XORP](http://www.xorp.org/livecd.html) as a LiveCD, and [GNU Zebra](http://www.zebra.org/download.html) as an installable routing daemon for GNU/Linux. On Windows Server there is [RRAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655.aspx) or other [manual ways](http://securearea.blogspot.com/2007/11/configuring-windows-as-pc-router.html) to [configure Windows as a router](http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html). A Windows software solution is [Nat32](http://www.nat32.com/).

Comment: I think I forgot to mention this...I need to set up a *wireless* access point, and the connecting computers should be able to see my computer's network as a wireless hotspot, not an adhoc network. I don't think the above methods allow me to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PC to dedicate to this, take a look at [Vyatta Community Edition](http://www.vyatta.org/) or [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/). Both are open source, and would give you more than just basic routing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think I forgot to mention this...I need to set up a wireless access point, and the connecting computers should be able to see my computer's network as a wireless hotspot, not an adhoc network. I don't think the above methods allow me to do that.

Comment: i think this is mentioned in the question.  you can always edit the question and add more details if needed (it's easier for folks to read there than here in an answer post).  welcome to SuperUser!

Answer (score 0):

Just plug wireless ethernet card into your PC. So now you can set up AP. As a mentioned above,  these software firewalls are smart enough to operate wireless card

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You just need to ensure that the wireless card that you use can support a **promiscuous** operation mode in addition to the other modes. This is what enables a wireless card to become an *access point* to other wireless cards. Not all wireless cards have this capability, which requires you to connect in ad-hoc mode instead.